# Is it possible to force a "get" method to a "post" form?

Tags: php, html

My website has a post method form just like below:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="text" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this also going to work if someone calls the login.php directly passing the parameters within the URL like below (forcing a get method)?

```
www.mysite.com/login.php?username=123456&password=123456
```

Comment: password in the URL string is probably not the most ideal scenario.

Comment: Yes, those are just post and get variables on the same page.

Comment: @ all - I don't think that people understand the question here. I think the OP is asking if someone enters hard coded values as a GET method, will it execute. @ op: correct?

Comment: If that's the case @Fred-ii- , I should change to no. If the server side check for get and post explicitly.

Comment: @frz3993 I *may* be wrong about grasping the question, but that's what I take from it. Will wait to see if OP's read my comment.

Comment: ^^ it so only if script get `$_REQUEST`

Comment: I wanted to know how PHP handles variables from "get" and "post" methods. It is clear now. Thanks

Comment: I did grasp the question then.

Comment: @ OP: Personally,  I think @splash58 made a much better point in comments about `$_REQUEST` and if that is used in your PHP which we don't know what it looks like, since you didn't post it, rather than the answer you accepted which doesn't really explain it, in regards to what the question was about. splash58 could (and should) submit an answer and with a good/added explanation which am sure will be good ;-) However, Half Crazed did also mention that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I appreciate your comment, however the answer proposed by etm124 is the one best one in my opinion. It was clear and directly to the point. I am not looking for best practices, I just wanted to know how PHP behaves with the different types of form methods.

Comment: I'm just a stickler for *detail* ;-) I'd of submitted an answer myself, since I know and understand how forms and its processes work with detailed explanation. But, you've got your solution and that's what counts. I was thinking of future visitors to the question.

Comment: Very appreciated your concern. I will take into consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access them independently.

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
   $username = $_POST['username'];
}
else{
   $username = $_GET['username'];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how `login.php`... does it use `$_POST`, `$_GET`, or `$_REQUEST`?

Using `$_GET` for a login form is not recommended and is very bad practice.

Comment: So far, I think this is the better answer (rather than what OP accepted earlier), since as you said, will depend on which code OP's using in their PHP.

Answer (score 0):

$_GET for a login is not ideal. This function will get the value from $_GET or $_POST.

```
function get($name){
    if(isset($_POST[$name])){
         return $_POST[$name];
    }else if(isset($_GET[$name])){
         return $_GET[$name];
    }
    return null;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not ideal to use $_GET with passwords as anyone can see it in the browser, anyway it's very easy to do. All you have to do is change your form tag to the following:

```
<form action="login.php" method="get">
```

As you can see method is now get instead of post.
In your php just use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`

If you'd rather the options of your php script to use POST or GET you can always check if GET is set, if so use GET otherwise check if there is a POST. Therefore using the form will use POST (more secure) and in the url it will use GET.
Try the following code:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['username']) && isset($_GET['password'])){
    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];
    $submitted = true;
}
else if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $submitted = true;
}

if($submitted){
   // Do your code here..
   // $username will give the username and $password will give the password.
}

?>
```

Hope it helps!